# How can the simulation proof of unsolvability of Byzantine Generals Problem be correct?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus

In the Lamport's paper on The Byzantine Generals Problem ([pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eluca/cs174/byzantine.pdf)) :

There is a proof of unsolvability in the trivial case where **N = 3 generals**, and **M = 1 traitor** (*page 384, 385*).
This is straightforward to follow.

The paper then goes on to give a simulation proof that (*page 386*) :

> ... no solution with fewer than **3M + 1** generals can cope with **m**
> traitors.

The proof is by contradiction and they say if 3M+1 generals with M traitors is solvable, then so is the trivial case of 3 generals and 1 traitor. But since 3 generals and 1 traitor is unsolvable, we arrive at a contradiction.

This just does not make sense or hold. My justifications :

1. The paper showed that the **trivial** case of **3 generals** and **1 traitor** is unsolvable **without using simulation**.
2. Therefore to make a claim that if **3M+1** generals and **M** traitors were solvable, the **trivial** case could be solvable and *since the trivial case is not solvable*, 3M+1 generals with M traitors is not solvable just does not hold because of **point 1**.

It seems that this is just an invalid circular reference.

Could some one please point out what I am missing here ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the circular reference here.

The claim is that for all M, there cannot be an algorithm that solves BGP for 3M generals and M traitors. (Note that this is not for 'some M', but rather for 'all M' - otherwise the 3 general 1 traitor case immediately implies the theorem.)

The proof is by contradiction. Assume that for some M - any given M - that we can solve BGP for 3M generals and M traitors using algorithm A. Then we can design an algorithm B that can solve the 3/1 case, by having each general simulate M generals, and then running algorithm A as a subroutine.

This is a contradiction because we know - independently - that no algorithm B that solves the 3/1 case can exist, concluding the proof.